# esp8266 request esp8266 http server code -1 (Arduino IDE)

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

two nodemcu device.

`device1`: create webserver and hotspot.

`device2`: connect hotspot, request web server, response -1, body empty.

I test device 1 webserver use browser from PC, success.

Test device 2, connect same route wifi, request my PC server, success.

I don't know why only (device2 request device1) or (device1 request device2) failed.

device1:

```cpp
  ESP8266WebServer server(80);
  server.on("/config", []() {
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "config");
  });
  server.begin();
```

device2:

```cpp
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin("http://192.168.4.1/config");
  int httpCode = http.GET();
  String payload = http.getString();
  http.end();
  Serial.printf("httpCode: %d, %s \n", httpCode, payload.c_str());
```

Comment: are you sure that device2 successful connected to SoftAP of device1?

Comment: Yes, device2 get the ip from hosport, and device1 print connected device present device1.

Answer (score 0):

`device2` must set

```
WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
```

I lost this. If you connect route, no `WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA)` can work.